# How to save the content of a XML file into a table (Oracle / PLSQL) without creating a directory

Tags: xml, oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

is it possible to save the content of an XML file in a table, without using something like "create directory"? 
(because that supposes that you have access to a directory on the Oracle Server and your file is on the server, but this isn't the case. The file is located on a local machine)

Or does anybody know if Apex provide something to upload a XML into a table?

Comment: Where is the file located? On the server or maybe your local machine?

Comment: Yep, local. That's the problem.

Comment: If it is a single file, can you not copy the contents of the file into a string variable and use that for your INSERT statement? Convert it to XMLTYPE first maybe.

Comment: PL/SQL runs in the database on the server.  So you can't use PL/SQL to read files stored on the client.  You would need an application that runs on the client that can read the file and connects to the database.  You could, for example, use `SQL*Loader` on the client.

Comment: The problem is, I have to "automate" this ;-( It is for a Apex application for translation purposes. And the girl who has to translate later, isn't that familiar with stuff like this and yeah, that's a problem. Otherwise (if it was for me) I would just do that.
That is the only thing that prevent me from completing the application ;-(

Comment: Ah okay, thanks Justin.

Comment: We has similar kind of situation in one of my project and we used DWH tool etl INFORMATICA to read the file and then store I in a table of column XMLTYPE. It worked pretty well for us.

Comment: Can you maybe linke something to it?
I'm a little bit of the search results with google ;D
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can use SQL*Loader, and run it from the script for better
   usability.
2. APEX has an ability to load files in the buffer table.
   Just make a dialog page with "File Browse" item. Look at it's "Storage Type" property. By default, this control loads your file into **www_flow_files** table.
3. You can use **xmltable** function to parse and insert XML data into table.

Comment: Ah okay, thanks!
I use the 3 one already to parse and insert XML data into my table. 
I get the XML from a table, but as I said, the problem was ... how to put the XML into the table ;D
But maybe the Apex aproach works for me. That would be nice ;-)
I mark your answer as accepted.